# change the color of grid plot -dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, charts, dojox.charting

i am using this code:

```
chart1.addPlot("grid", {
type: "Grid", 
hMinorLines: true
});
```

how i can change the color of the grid, and the interval between each line ?
It is possible, right?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Grid's intervals between lines are determined by the tick step parameters you give to the axis. So if you want major horizontal lines/ticks for every integer, and minor horizontal lines for every .25, you can do:

```
chart1.addAxis("y", {
    ...
    majorTickStep: 1, 
    minorTickStep: 0.25
});
```

To change the color of the grid lines, the only way I know of is to manipulate the theme you are using.

```
var myTheme = dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.blue; // Or any other theme

myTheme.axis.majorTick.color = "green";
myTheme.axis.minorTick.color = "red";

chart1.setTheme(myTheme);
```

Comment: You can use majorHLine, minorHLine, majorVLine, minorVLine options for changing colors. At least for dojo 1.8 and up (not sure about the previous versions).